# Restart MySQL Service If there is no PID (Process ID) in Ubuntu

Tags: mysql, shell, ubuntu, cron

I created a cron job to start MySQL server if it is stopped unexpectedly. It is working fine, sometimes it starts but MySQL is not working. If I check status there is no PID.

```
root@techbrij:~# service mysql status
mysql start/running
```

Now I want to change the cron job and restart the service if there is no MySQL PID.

Answer (score 0):

You have to execute this script from **root crontab**:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ ! "$(/usr/sbin/service mysql status)" =~ "start/running" ]]
then
    /usr/sbin/service mysql start
fi
```

To check if there is no PID:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql="$(pgrep mysql)"
if [ -z "$mysql" ]
then
    /usr/sbin/service mysql start
fi
```

Comment: I used similar script, the problem is that sometimes service is started but it is not working. at this moment there is no PID. I need if condition when there is no pid restart the service

Comment: I edited my answer for this condition. To be modified for your own usage.